# How to upload images to different urls by using ckeditor?

Tags: php, image, upload, ckeditor

There are 2 pages using ckeditor on my website. (page A and page B)

I know if I wanna upload images, I have to change codes in ckfinder\config.php, 
just like:

```
$baseUrl = '/myweb/ckedit/upload/';
```

but the urls of page A and page B are different.

I use ↓

```
if($_GET['page']==A){
  //this is url of A
}else{
  //this is url of B
}
```

to try to make the different urls, but it failed.
（ I also change other codes, like `$baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);` , but the same. :( ）
Is there any better way to solve my question? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Why do you want a different upload location? Cant you add a prefix to the image-names?

Comment: The url of page B may be changed someday, so I wonder if the upload location can be different.

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Upload-files-multiple-folders-based-different-page You basically give every instance of ckeditor a different id and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just got it. XD

1. `session_start();` in ckfinder\config.php on line 1.
2. on line 63:

   ```
   if($_SESSION['page']==A){
       $baseUrl = url_A;
   }else{
       $baseUrl = url_B;
   }
   ```

Remember to set SESSION on your pages.

Comment: What if user opens to different pages in two different tabs? Use id wisely as suggested by Gudgip.